# jmeter - How to ignore selected samplers from getting measured in the *jtl file

Tags: jmeter

My test configuration :

Loop Controller

```
--> Beanshell Sampler 

        vars.put("test", "${__CSVRead(*test,0)}");
        Add it to an existing array retrieved from vars.getObject
```

In the above scenario, I am constructing my request payload dynamically in a loop controller. I had to put the CSVRead function in a separate Beanshell sampler under the loop controller since "${__CSVRead(*test,0)}" was reading the sample line if I use it within a for loop inside the beanshell sampler (interpreted mode).

While the above configuration meets my requirement, my *.jtl files are growing in size even for a 30 minute load test since the BeanShell sampler is getting measured all the time. While I am able to filter the required data by using the FilterResults tool, I want to know how to avoid this during the execution itself like the TestActionSampler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by using the following configuration.

```
Loop Controller
 --> Test Action Sampler
   --> Beanshell timer returning 0 at the end
        vars.put("test", "${__CSVRead(*test,0)}");
        Add it to an existing array retrieved from vars.getObject
        return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the following Test Elements instead:

- [BeanShell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor)
- [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor)
- [Beanshell Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Timer)

By default Timers and Pre/Post Processors execution time **is not included** into parent sampler elapsed time (unless you use [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) explicitly configured to do so), using this approach you will be able to exclude the time, required for constructing payload from test results.

Comment: Thanks. While I was aware of this, directly adding the beanshell pre/post processor and timers to the loop controller didn't work. I had to add a Test Action Sampler to achieve this

Comment: Make sure you understand the consequence of switching from a BeanShell Sampler to a pre/post processor. If you were using the BeanShell Sampler to do some "once-per-thread" type of scripting, replacing it with one of these will not give you equivalent results. Your code could be executed "once-per-sample" depending on where you put the pre/post processor.