# Jmeter: I want to pass the same random value in all http requests under the same threadGroup per thread

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, beanshell

I have the following JMeter project

I want to use the same var value in all the HTTP requests under the Thread Group, 
per thread, Next thread should have new value for all HTTP requests.

I know that `CSV Data Set Config` will work, but I don't want to construct the file and also want random picks and not serial parsing of the files.

Currently, in `Setup Thread Group`, I'm reading the two files and use beanShellPeProcessor Random Customer and Articles to pick random values from an ArrayList.

But every HTTP request gets a `nes` value, even if I move the random picking `BeanShell` under the Thread Group.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: what's your code for random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create **Beanshell Sampler** under **Thread Group** as first request in Thread Group

This way it will be executed before other requests and will be called 1 per Thread.

Comment: Thans.
Works partially.
But this way, the "BeanShell Sampler" is included in the "Aggreagte Report".
This is minus.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903467/jmeter-how-to-ignore-selected-samplers-from-getting-measured-in-the-jtl-file or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412649/how-to-ignore-login-and-logout-requests-in-jmeter

Comment: Or you can Add it as PeProcessor child of first request `HTTP Request SWS Customers

Comment: This 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412649/how-to-ignore-login-and-logout-requests-in-jmeter 
suits me. 
Thanks.